# What is a straight wing on an airplane?

Tags: aircraft-design

What is a straight wing? I need this for my science project. I have looked for other answers on this website, but I cannot find any. Please help!

Comment: It's a wing that [is not swept](http://aviationweek.com/site-files/aviationweek.com/files/uploads/2015/07/Windshear-wing_sweep_effect.jpg).

Answer (score 4):

*What is a straight wing on an airplane?*

A straight wing is a wing that is not swept (see the images).

[image: Straight and swept wimgs]
*[Straight and swept wings](http://paperaeroplanes.com/blog/?p=73)*

[image: The unswept wings]
*[Unswept, straight wings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swept_wing)*

[image: Swept wings] 
*[Swept wings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swept_wing)*

Comment: Please edit your answer to include the attributions for the images.